# Jmeter POST and PUT request body data not received

Tags: node.js, jmeter, httprequest

I have been trying for quite some time and I have applied the solutions available on StackOverflow.

I am not able to receive the POST or PUT request body data in my API. The following are my configurations for Jmeter and the code snippet. The output is always "undefined"

[image]

[image]

Here is the Node.js code:

```
app.post('/testing', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Output is `undefined`

Comment: I'm guessing you are using express. Are you using the bodyparser middleware? http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: @Evert you are right. I was using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` instead I was supposed to use ` app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

instead, I was supposed to use

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Thank you @Evert

Answer (score 0):

you should add the HTTP Header Manager listener. with the following configuration and try again:

[image configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIUzu.png)